# Order a set of translations, according to a specific language

Tags: c#, nhibernate, hql

Assuming two classes `Product` and `ProductTranslation`. The product has a property `Product.Title`, which is a set of `ProductTranslation`.
If I have two languages, e.g. `en` and `de` in my system, the set of `Product.Title` would hold two entries for each product.

Is there any way to formulate a HQL which returns me a list of products, ordered by a *specific* language, e.g. `en`? Or is this kind of sorting only possible after the DB-access within memory, e.g. with Linq or any comparator?

Thx for any ideas!
sl3dg3

Edit: Despite the ordering I still would like to receive the whole set of `ProductTranslation`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a possible solution: It can be done with a double-join:

```
FROM Product AS product
INNER JOIN FETCH product.Translations ordered_trans
INNER JOIN FETCH product.Translations trans
WHERE ordered_trans.language = 'en'
ORDER BY ordered_trans.Title ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear whether you mean ordering using a particular culture, or just simple ordering according to the matching translations. If it's the latter, that just sounds like a join. In LINQ it would be something like:

```
string language = "en";
var query = from product in db.Product
            join translation in db.ProductTranslation
                                  .Where(t => t.Language == language)
                 on product.Id equals translation.productId
            orderby translation.Title
            select new { Product = product, translation.Title };
```

I don't know what the equivalent HQL would be, but I'm sure HQL handles joins with no problems... (If you can use LINQ to NHibernate, that should handle it fine too of course.)

EDIT: Just looking at the HQL docs, I *suspect* you can use

```
from Product as product
inner join fetch product.Translations translation
where translation.language = 'en'
order by translation.title asc
```

Comment: I mean ordering according to a particular culture. If I hit english, I would like the titles ordered according to the english translation, otherwise according to the german ones. Yes, with linq it is no problem, but I still can't make up my mind how that should work with HQL.

Comment: @sl3dg3: No, I think you missed my point about culture vs just title - different cultures will order the same words differently. Editing to *try* some HQL...

Comment: @ Jon: Yeah you are right, culture would matter of course. But for the sake of simplicity it should be ordered culture invariant. As for your example, I missed to outline one important point: I would like to receive the whole set of languages. In that case I would receive only english. And another important point: `ProductTranslation` does not have any mapped back-reference. I think this two key-points make it impossible...